# Проблема с аргументами функции

Tags: c, функции, указатели, объявление, параметры

Суть вопроса такова. Нужно добавить структуру в список. Но выскакивает ошибка: `void push(avia *,int,char *,char *)`: невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из `avia **` в `avia *`. Не понимаю в чём дело.

Вот кейс:

```
if (uslovie == true)
{

    int number;
    char destination[10];
    char time[10];

    printf("Vvedite nomer: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Vvedite punkt: ");
    gets_s(destination);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Vvedite vremya: ");
    gets_s(time);
    printf("\n");

    system("cls");

    push(&head, number, destination, time);
    printf("Element uspeshno dobavlen!\n");
    system("pause");
    break;
}

else
    printf("Sozdaite spisok!\n");

system("pause");
break;
```

А вот вызываемая функция:

```
void push(avia **head, int number, char *destination, char *time)
{
    avia *tmp = (avia*)malloc(sizeof(avia));
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        tmp->number = number;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tmp->destination[i] = destination[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tmp->time[i] = time[i];
        tmp->next = NULL;
        *head = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp->number = number;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tmp->destination[i] = destination[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tmp->time[i] = time[i];
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: А нужного куска в вопросе нет...

Comment: @Qwertiy а какой нужен? инициализация?

Comment: Вы, очевидно, нас обманываете. Код некомпилируем в первую очередь потому, что у функции `get_s` два параметра, а не один. И именно эта ошибка будет отрапортована компилятором еще до вызова `push`.  Ту же ошибку, которую вы процитировали, объяснить приведенным пока кодом невозможно.

Comment: @corpsolovei, объявление и присваивание `head` из первого фрагмента.

Comment: @AnT, в Си++ [есть](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597963/178988) перегрузка `gets_s` с одним параметром.

Comment: @Qwertiy: При чем здесь С++??? Внимательно смотрите заголовок и тэги: это С.

Comment: @AnT, вероятно, он на нём пишет, на самом деле ;)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, зачем эта пачка сомнительных тегов?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Телепатов нет. В вопросе сказано С - значит С. Никакого "на самом деле".

Comment: @AnT, телепаты есть :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас параметры в предварительном объявлении функции и параметры в ее определении не соответствуют друг другу.

Функция объявлена как

```
void push(avia *,int,char *,char *): 
          ^^^^^^
```

В то время, как в ее определении первый параметр имеет другой тип

```
void push(avia **head, int number, char *destination, char *time)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    //...
```

очевидно в предварительном объявлении функции имеется опечатка. Она должна быть объявлена также, как и в определении.

К тому же в определении функции код дублируется, и строки, если вы имеете дело именно со строками в качестве значений полей структуры, неправильно копируются.

Определение функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void push(avia **head, int number, char *destination, char *time)
{
    avia *tmp = (avia*)malloc(sizeof(avia));

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        tmp->number = number;

        strncpy( tmp->destination, destination, 10 );
        tmp->destination[9] = '\0';

        strncpy( tmp->time, time, 10 );
        tmp->time[9] = '\0';

        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }
}
```

Будет еще лучше, если функция будет объявлена как

```
void push(avia **head, int number, const char *destination, const char *time);
                                   ^^^^^                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52526/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow----).